# how to create a list a two columns list with variables in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a two column list with two variables.
the variables are two outputs that I get, and I need to make a list with them.
vara
varb
list=[vara,varb]
how do I create, print and initialize?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by warning you that this sort of question does not fly on Stack Overflow. I don't take personal issue with it, but I'd be cautious about asking similar questions - that is to say, questions that are vague and demonstrate a lack of independent research - in the future, as members here have a reputation of being fairly unkind to people that ask such questions.

That out of the way, I'll answer the question as best I can, with what little information I have. It *sounds* like you've got two variables, let's give them some random numerical values:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

and you want to know how to make a list with two elements made up of these two variables. In that case, you do it like this:

```
# two variables
a = 1
b = 2

# make a list
my_list = [a, b]
```

Easy as that.